# What format is this, is it salted, how to solve for salt?

Tags: password-cracking

I am using a third party app which stores tokens inside of a mysql db. I need to confirm the tokens but there is no easy way to get the actual values from the DB due to the interface. Long story short, I have the following example of what I see in the DB and what the actual value is. It seems like a hash with salt is what is going on here, thoughts?

Moreover, is it possible to figure out the salt? Are there tools like JtR that would help? Which one is best?

**Eaxmple:**

```
 db value      : ZsYEUGylYF/lwOblFU4oOlBEopHQICR2NBvtXzFjTsmHkyNXqW9JgTCM4RK07qUGf/1sjFF+agk=
 actual value  : nkze3fhhcoyqm76kdq1a6m3e1uohe656ils04iorkwbgc1k3y7
 salt          : seems to have 6 char salt?
```

**Notes:**

Q: is this just base64encoded with salt?  A: probably?

Q: If two users use the same value?  A: Produces the same hash.

Q: If the value changes in size, is the hash the same length?
A: No. For example value 'a' made a hash of "2BwphZk50OI="  (much smaller)

Q: is there a max length.
A: Not really, seems like the DB input allows a max 183 chars for input.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a reverse engineering problem and not a security problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reverse engineer the function that encrypts/decrypts the data to be sure. You can't salt a base64 value, it appears the choice for using base64 is due to the data not being "text friendly" and presumably long enough that hexencoding is inefficient.

Observing that the same users get the same value means a fixed salt, or no salt. And the length changes suggests its not a hash, but rather (symmetric?) encryption.

Good luck